# Websphere based SOAP over JMS Example

Tags: web-services, soap, jms, websphere

Can anyone point to some tutorial on how to implement WebSphere based SOAP over JMS WebServices?

I am specifically looking for WSDL sample, client and server side projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this: [Develop a SOAP/JMS JAX-WS Web services application with WebSphere Application Server V7 and Rational Application Developer V7.5](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/tutorials/0903_adams/index.html)